# how to give input to a command line?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

i need a help on how to give input to  a command prompt using a batch file..
for example- 
if i run the command mysql -u root -p to open my mysql server and it asks for password.. how i m gonna give that password to it using a batch file...
pls help me i am little new to it

Answer (score 0):

Just specify the password besides -p in batch file. Eg: if `username` is **Ankit** and `password` is **Devil**, specify the following in the batch file:

```
mysql -uAnkit -pDevil
```

Comment: Thanks for ur time.. but i have tried giving that.. yet it asks for a password and give the error no database found of that name in password field..

Comment: can u give the relevant code areas of your batch file. I believe that there is some typo there

Comment: Actually i am just reading information and haven't written it yet... Can u please help me on that... Ur help would be of great appreciation.. thanks

Comment: @AnkitDevil What are you specifically trying to achieve using this batch file ?

Comment: What is your MySQL version ? If is <= 5.5, try:

mysql  --user="root" --password="qwerty"

Answer (score 0):

Ask for the input using `Set /P`, e.g.

```bat
Set /P "pwd=Please enter your password: "
```

You can then use the variable `%pwd%` in your command string, e.g.

```bat
mysql -u root -p %pwd% …
```

You could also use the same method to request the user name too:

```bat
Set /P "usr=Please enter your user name: "
Set /P "pwd=Please enter your password: "
mysql -u %usr% -p %pwd% …
```

*Type `Set /?` at the Command Prompt for the command's usage information.*